# Getting value undefined error in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am having this playbook

```
---
- hosts: all
  handlers:
  - name: user-create
    user: name=oracle state=present
  tasks:
  - name: "check user"
    command: /usr/bin/id oracle
    register: output
    notify: user-create
    when: output.rc == 1
```

But whenever i run this on a system where oracle user is not there, running into this error

> "failed": true,
>       "msg": "The conditional check 'output.rc == 1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.rc == 1): 'output' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/user-check.yml': line 10, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: \"check user\"\n    ^ here\n"

Comment: `when` statement is evaluated **before** task execution, and `output` variable is populated **after** task execution. What is your goal?

Comment: Hello Konstantin,
                            My goal is to check if oracle user exists, thene delete it and recreate the user. Thats why i am registering the output and then if the rc is 1, notifying the handler.Ps guide me on how to achieve the same

Comment: Your requirement is not idempotent, it will delete/create user every playbook run. This is bad pattern. Take a look at @techraf's answer. Just add task with `state=absent` if you want to always recreate user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering based on comment:

> Actually i wanto check if the user exists, id it exists delete and recreate the user

The correct way to do it in Ansible is:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: ensure user 'oracle' does not exist
      user: name=oracle state=absent

    - name: ensure user 'oracle' exists
      user: name=oracle state=present
```

And that's all.

Ansible takes care not to try to create a user if it already exists; and not to try to delete a user if it doesn't.

Comment: Actually i wanto check if the user exists, id it exists delete and recreate the user

Comment: @achak01 Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks techraf, ur solution worked. But what if i want to do this in this way

check for user 1 
     if user 1 exsist perform xyz
 if user 1 does not exist
          perform abc

How do i achieve the above using ansible ?